# Does GlobalNames work on a stand-alone DNS server?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

Inspired from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1010304/6352).

`GlobalNames` is a special zone in Windows DNS servers that can resolve single-label names.

The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731744(v=ws.11)) says:

> We also recommend that the GlobalNames zone be integrated with Active
>   Directory Domain Services (AD DS). This integration with AD DS ensures
>   easier management and future scalability.

but this doesn't appear to be a requirement.

And yet, if you don't AD-integrate the zone, it doesn't appear to work.

Does this feature work in stand-alone Windows DNS servers? Or does it really require the DNS zone to be AD-integrated?

---

### Edit: test steps

OS: Windows Server 2019
Stand-alone server, not domain member.

- Installed DNS Server
- Verified that the DNS server can succesfuly resolve names such as `www.google.com` and `www.google.com.` (yes, I know about ending dots in DNS)
- Created a primary forward-lookup DNS zone called `GlobalNames`
- Enabled GlobalNames support using `Set-DnsServerGlobalNameZone -Enabled $True`
- Restarted DNS service just to be sure
- Created a CNAME record called `google` pointing to `www.google.com.`
- Tried to resolve `google` against local server:

  - Launched `nslookup`
  - `server 127.0.0.1`
  - google
  - google.
- Both failed.
- Tried also creating an A record pointing to an arbitrary IP address.
- Tried to resolve the A record as above (both with and without ending dot), same failure.

Comment: It does not require a domain, or AD-integration.  Can you be more specific (like evidence) of "it doesn't appear to work"  can you show exactly what you what you hvae done?

Comment: @Semicolon see edit.